# Objective-C compacting several SQL statements

Tags: objective-c, sqlite, ipad

I have an app that talks to an SQL database, an example table consist of OBSERVATIONSID (primary key), LEVEL0, LEVEL1, LEVEL2, LEVEL3, LEVEL4, EDITABLE.

Currently each time i want to a row, i 
read the database to ensure row doesn't already exist.
store the data
read the database again to get the just added primary key.

Storing Data

```
+ (void) ObservationsEditSaveData : (NSString*) Level1 : (NSString*) Level2 : (NSString*)Level3 : (NSString*) Level4 : (NSString*) Level0{
    sqlite3_stmt *updateStmt;

    sqlite3_open([dbObservationPathString UTF8String], &ObservationDB);
    NSString* updateSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"INSERT INTO OBSERVATIONS(LEVEL0, LEVEL1, LEVEL2, LEVEL3, LEVEL4, EDITABLE)  values (?,?,?,?,?,?)"];

    sqlite3_prepare_v2(ObservationDB, [updateSQL UTF8String], -1, &updateStmt, NULL);
    if(sqlite3_step(updateStmt)==SQLITE_DONE)
    {
        sqlite3_bind_text(updateStmt, 1, [Level0 UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(updateStmt, 2, [Level1 UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(updateStmt, 3, [Level2 UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(updateStmt, 4, [Level3 UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(updateStmt, 5, [Level4 UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_int(updateStmt, 6, 0);
        sqlite3_step(updateStmt);
        sqlite3_finalize(updateStmt);
    }
    sqlite3_close(ObservationDB);
}
```

Reading ID / Checking if exist. (On checking if exist, if ID is returned i assume it exists)

```
+ (int) ObservationGetID : (NSString*) Level1 : (NSString*) Level2 : (NSString*) Level3 : (NSString*) Level4 : (NSString*) Level0{
    int ReturnValue = 0;
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;

    if (sqlite3_open([dbObservationPathString UTF8String], &ObservationDB)==SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSString *querySql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT OBSERVATIONSID FROM OBSERVATIONS WHERE LEVEL0 = '%@' AND LEVEL1 = '%@' AND LEVEL2 = '%@' AND LEVEL3 = '%@' AND LEVEL4 = '%@'", Level0 ,Level1, Level2, Level3, Level4];
        const char* query_sql = [querySql UTF8String];

        if (sqlite3_prepare(ObservationDB, query_sql, -1, &statement, NULL)==SQLITE_OK)
        {
            while (sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_ROW)
            {
                 ReturnValue = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0);
            }
        }
    }
    sqlite3_close(ObservationDB);
    return ReturnValue;
}
```

What id like to do is reduce the number of sql calls, can i combine these commands into one?

Btw if I've messed up the code generally please say, i won't be offended.

Thanks

Comment: BTW, your `observationGetID` method should probably use `sqlite3_bind_xxx` functions, like you did in `observationsEditSaveData`. You never want to build SQL with `stringWithFormat`. And if you find binding values like that too cumbersome, consider using [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb), which makes writing solid SQLite code much easier. Also, it is generally advised to open your database only once, rather than opening and closing it with every method call.

Comment: so to do this, would i sqlite3_step then do all the bindings? then have             while (sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_ROW)
            {
                 ReturnValue = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0);
            } im confused how the sqlite3_bind_text and the sqlite3_column_int go together

Comment: See the code sample below. Bottom line, the step function will actually perform the SQL. But clearly you do not want to perform SQL until you bind the values. So bind to first, then step.

Comment: In `observationGetID`, you'd `sqlite3_prepare_v2`, `sqlite3_bind_xxx` for all of the columns of the `WHERE` clause, and then have your `while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)` loop in which you retrieve columns with `sqlite3_column_xxx`.

Comment: yeah that makes perfect sense, i got confused with what did what. So much unclear advice out there

Comment: BTW, you should make sure your `observationGetID` calls `sqlite3_finalize` when done. Every `sqlite3_prepare_v2` must be accompanied by a `sqlite3_finalize` to free its memory. (Once you finish this project, you should seriously contemplate FMDB which gets you out of the weeds of `sqlite3_finalize` and all the `sqlite3_bind_xxx` calls, etc. It's much easier.)

Comment: i will defo look into FMDB, when i got over this hurdle, thanks alot everything has now made perfect sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are invoking `sqlite3_step` (in your `if` clause) before binding values. You have to bind values first, and only then perform the SQL with `sqlite3_step`. Just remove that `if` clause with the `sqlite3_step`.

---

You can change the `observationsEditSaveData` method so that:

1. Call `bind` functions before `step` function.
2. Have the function return the row id of the inserted row (zero means there was an error).
3. Check the result of all of the SQLite calls.
4. Conform to [Cocoa naming conventions](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001281-BBCHBFAH) (starting method and variable names with lowercase letters).

This yields:

```
+ (sqlite3_int64) observationsEditSaveData : (NSString*) level1 : (NSString*) level2 : (NSString*)level3 : (NSString*) level4 : (NSString*) level0 {
    sqlite3_stmt *updateStmt;

    if (sqlite3_open([dbObservationPathString UTF8String], &observationDB) != SQLITE_OK) {
        NSLog(@"open failed");
        return 0;
    }

    const char *updateSQL = "INSERT INTO OBSERVATIONS(LEVEL0, LEVEL1, LEVEL2, LEVEL3, LEVEL4, EDITABLE)  values (?,?,?,?,?,?)";

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(observationDB, updateSQL, -1, &updateStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
        NSLog(@"prepare failed: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(observationDB));
    if (sqlite3_bind_text(updateStmt, 1, [level0  UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT) != SQLITE_OK)
        NSLog(@"bind 1 failed: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(observationDB));
    if (sqlite3_bind_text(updateStmt, 2, [level1  UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT) != SQLITE_OK)
        NSLog(@"bind 2 failed: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(observationDB));
    if (sqlite3_bind_text(updateStmt, 3, [level2  UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT) != SQLITE_OK)
        NSLog(@"bind 3 failed: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(observationDB));
    if (sqlite3_bind_text(updateStmt, 4, [level3  UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT) != SQLITE_OK)
        NSLog(@"bind 4 failed: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(observationDB));
    if (sqlite3_bind_text(updateStmt, 5, [level4  UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT) != SQLITE_OK)
        NSLog(@"bind 5 failed: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(observationDB));
    if (sqlite3_bind_int(updateStmt, 6, 0))
        NSLog(@"bind 1 failed: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(observationDB));
    if (sqlite3_step(updateStmt) != SQLITE_DONE)
        NSLog(@"step failed: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(observationDB));
    sqlite3_finalize(updateStmt);

    sqlite3_int64 rowid = sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(observationDB);

    sqlite3_close(observationDB);

    return rowid;
}
```

Comment: is there any way this can be easily adapted so, it checks the row dos not already exist before adding, ive read about "insert if not exist" but on my attempts it failed completly

Comment: @user1603332 You could just call `observationGetID` first, to see if there's a value out there, and if not, then call your `observationsEditSaveData`. Maybe I'm not understanding the question.

Comment: no thats the way im doing it atm but was wondering if there was a way it could be combined into one sql call just for better coding really

Comment: just seems daft to call the database to see if it exists, if not call the database to put the data in, then finally call the database again to get the ID of the data ive just put in.

Comment: @user1603332 There is the `INSERT OR REPLACE` syntax, but that's using the primary key to decide, which is not applicable here. Some people might be inclined to (a) put an alternate unique key on the table; and (b) just `INSERT` (ignoring if it's already there and generates an error), but I don't think that's good practice. In terms of getting the unique ID, you don't have to re-`SELECT`, though. You can just call [`sqlite3_last_insert_rowid`](http://sqlite.org/c3ref/last_insert_rowid.html) (assuming `OBSERVATIONSID` is defined as `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT`).

Comment: @user1603332 See revised answer with modified rendition of `observationsEditSaveData` that returns the row id (so you can determine the success or failure of the insert, as well as get the `OBSERVATIONSID` value).